# Liferay - public render parameter are cached / wrong

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

I have a very basic requirement. Two portlets are on one page. The first one receives a parameter, does some calculation and sets a new parameter as a public render parameter. The second portlet should just display this value. Easy, right? So I tried to do that. Here is the action method of the first portlet which just receives a parameter and sets a public render parameter.

```
public void testAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
   long someNumber = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "someNumber");
   actionResponse.setRenderParameter("number", someNumber + "");
}
```

The render method of the second portlet is even more basic:

```
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
    long number = ParamUtil.getLong(renderRequest, "number");
    renderRequest.setAttribute("number", number);
    super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
}
```

In the view.jsp of that second portlet I am just displaying that 'number'.
Now, I generate an action url with 'someNumber' set to 2 and a second one with 'someNumber' to 5. Now I copy the first url and open it in a new tab. The second portlet shows me the value 2 for 'number', which is correct. I copy the second url and also get value 2 for 'number', although it should display 5. If I debug the code I can see that the public render parameter in the first portlet is set to 5, but still the second portlet shows me the value 2. If I do it the other way around, so opening the second url first and then the other one, I get value 5 in both tabs. Somehow the value is cached. Why?
Both portlets have the annotation `javax.portlet.supported-public-render-parameter=number`

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. You have to set the following property in your portlet class.

```
"javax.portlet.init-param.copy-request-parameters=false"
```

If this is set to `true`, the method `copyRequestParameters` will set the render params back to old values. This might be a Liferay bug.
By the way, this property was set to `false` by default in Liferay 6. That's why I noticed this issue since the migration to Liferay 7.